# C-Array of Pointers different ways of indexing

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

main () {
    char *line[5];
    int i;
    line[0] = "line 1";
    line[1] = "line 2";
    line[2] = "line 3";
    line[3] = "line 4";
    line[4] = "line 5";

    char *p;
    p=line[2];
    //*p = *(p+2);  //gives error as segmentation fault.
    printf("\n coming here : %s",*line); //works fine
    printf("\n coming here : %s",*line++); //gives error "invalid increment in main"
    printf("\n coming here : %s",*(line+2)++); //error, i assumed it will work as *(line+2) is also a pointer
    printf("%c",*(line[4]+1));//works, prints character 'i'
    printf("%c",**(line+4));//segmentation error, i assumed it to print character 'l'
}
```

I was trying this program and faced few errors as I have mentioned in the comments beside each line of code.

with char *line[5] i was trying to achieve a array of pointers each pointer element of this array pointing to a string.

Please help me clarify what all I am doing wrong here. Thanks.

### Edit 1:

I have included only part of the example, please see the writelines function. Rest of this example is pretty straight forward this did not include it.

```
#define MAXLINES 5000 /* max #lines to be sorted */ 
char *lineptr[MAXLINES]; /* pointers to text lines */

int readlines(char *lineptr[], int maxlines)
{
    int len, nlines;
    char *p, line[MAXLEN];
    nlines = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLEN)) > 0)
        if (nlines >= maxlines || p = alloc(len) == NULL) return -1;
        else {
            line[len-1] = '\0'; /* delete newline */ strcpy(p, line);
            lineptr[nlines++] = p;
        }
    return nlines;
}

/* writelines: write output lines */
void writelines(char *lineptr[], int nlines)
{
    while (nlines-- > 0)
        printf("%s\n", *lineptr++); // this is where they are incrementing array, which you said is incorrect.
}
```

### Edit 2:

```
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *line[] = {"linawee 1", "lipe 2", "lint 3", "linr 4"};
    while (--argc > 0) //command line input has same number of elements as 'line'
    {
        printf("%s%s", *++argv, (argc > 1) ? " " : ""); //works just fine.
        printf("%s", *++line); //error
    }
}
```

Please explain the above prog, why it works for one and gives error for other.
Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes you are using correct constructions like `p=line[2];`, but sometimes you are trying to do something very strange. So, what is your problem? Just use standard ways to access elements of array (i.e. `line[i]`) and everything will be ok.

Comment: One of the best lines for understanding is `printf("%c",*(line[4]+1));` (here you are getting access to second character of fifth line, because `line[4]` is pointer on fifth string and `+1` increases it (so you get pointer on next character "i"))

Comment: note that the syntax `line[i]` is just syntactic sugar for `*(line+i)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, let's iterate through the errors:

#### Line 1:

```
*p = *(p+2);
```

You're modifying a string literal. That's not allowed.

#### Line 2:

```
printf("\n coming here : %s", *line);
```

`*line` will result in the same value as `line[0]`, so this all makes sense.

#### Line 3:

```
printf("\n coming here : %s", *line++);
```

`line` is an array. You're not allowed to increment arrays. So `line++` is invalid.

#### Line 4:

```
printf("\n coming here : %s", *(line+2)++);
```

This actually means:

```
printf("\n coming here : %s", *(line + 2);
(line + 2) = (line + 2) + 1;
```

Which is invalid, because you can't assign to `line + 2`.

#### Line 5:

```
printf("%c", *(line[4]+1));
```

Yep thats fine. We take the string at index 4, and then grab the character in it at index 1.

#### Line 6:

```
printf("%c", **(line+4));
```

This should work fine. It's not clear why you are getting an error.

#### With regards to edit 1:

```
void func(char *lineptr[]) {
    *lineptr++;
}
```

For whatever reason, C allows you to use array notation during function calls. In this case, when you have a function parameter of: `char *lineptr[]`, it is treated as `char **lineptr`.

Therefore, in this case, you're actually incrementing a pointer, not an array, which is why it's allowed.

Note however, that the increments to the pointer are only visible inside the function. That is, if I do:

```
int main() {
    char * arr[] = {"hi", "how", "are", "you"};
    inc(arr);
    // arr[0] still points to "hi"
}

void inc(char *arr[]) {
    // arr[0] points to "hi"
    arr++;
    // arr[0] now points to "how"
}
```

#### With regards to edit 2:

```
char *line[] = {"linawee 1", "lipe 2", "lint 3", "linr 4"};
printf("%s", *++line);
```

You're incrementing an array. You're not allowed to do that. You certainly could do:

```
printf("%s", line[3]);
printf("%s", *(line + 3)
```

Comment: Your transformation of line 4 transforms pre-increment instead of post-increment. Of course, both are invalid for the same reason but I'd suggest you edit it, some beginners in C confuse operator precedence and order of evaluation.

Comment: @mafso I disagree. If I did a preincrement, I would call printf on `*(line + 3)`, which I don't. The assignment happening before or after the `printf()` call is unspecified.

Comment: It happened (if it could happen at all, it's an assignment to a non-lvalue, of course) _after_ the `printf` call. A function call is a sequence point. And what I suggested: `printf("...: %s", *(line + 2); (line + 2) = (line + 2) + 1` (removed `"`, obviously a typo).

Comment: I think, I was a little vague: Replacing `line + 2` by `l` (and assuming `l` was a modifiable lvalue): `printf("%s", *l++);` would be equivalent to `printf("%s", *l); l++;`, not to `l++; printf("%s", *l);`.

Comment: @mafso: Yep. I see what you're getting at now. The screwy lvalue confused me. Thanks! (And also thanks for noting the extraneous `"`).

Comment: @sharth thanks for this ans, cleared my doubts. I nw recall having read that we cannot increment array pointers with ++, however would 3 have worked if i had used +1 instead of ++?

Comment: @sharth : I was trying this by taking que from an example from Dennis Ritchie Ansi C. I will edit the question to add the example i am talking about. Kindly comment on how i went wrong in understanding that example.

Comment: @CodeWithPride: I've added some comments about the two edits.

Comment: @sharth : thanks for the comments, your comment for edit 1 actually helped understand edit 2 as well .. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

See: [lvalue required as increment operand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364445/lvalue-required-as-increment-operand)

line is not a pointer to dynamic memory, it is an array declared on the stack. So line++ is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

String literals may not be changed though in C they have types of non-const character arrays. In this statement

```
//*p = *(p+2);  //gives error as segmentation fault
```

you are trying to change the string literal pointed by p.

As for other errors then arrays in expressions are converted to `rvalue` of pointers to the first element of arrays. You may not increase an `rvalue`. For it would be clear then for example expression

```
(line+2)++
```

in fact is equivalent to the following code

```
int x = 0;

( x + 2 )++;
```

Here the compiler will issue an error because expression `( x + 2 )` is not a `lvalue`

Answer (score 0):

You have one problem here

You are trying to assign an rvalue (layman terms: value that should be in the right side of equation, and constants that you should not modify)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main () {
    char *line[5];
    line[0] = "line 1";
    line[1] = "line 2";
    line[2] = "line 3";
    line[3] = "line 4";
    line[4] = "line 5";
    char *p;
    p=line[2];
//  *p = *(p+2);  // *p is a gives you  a character, this means you are trying to assign character with character?
    p = p + 2; // correct way
    printf("%s\n", p); // outputs: "ine 3", expected
    printf("coming here : %s\n",*line); // this is fine
//    printf("\n coming here : %s",*line++); //  Same reason as above and below
//    printf("\n coming here : %s",*(line+2)++); //*(line + 2)++ means *(line + 2) = *(line + 2) + 1 => see the error?
    printf("%c\n",*(line[4]+1)); //works, prints character 'i'
    printf("%c\n",**(line+4));// this prints l on my machine and is valid.
    return 0;
}
```