# why foo((&i)++) gives Lvalue required error. There is no array associated

Tags: c, reference, lvalue

I understand a few things about Lvalue but I don't understand how the below code gives an error:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void foo(int *);

int main() 
{
   int i=10;
   foo((&i)++);
}

void foo(int *p)
{
    printf("%d",*p);
}
```

6:13: error: lvalue required as increment operand
     foo((&i)++);
             ^

Comment: Because `&i` is not an *lvalue*, and the `++` operator requires one. It's roughly equivalent to `&i = &i + 1;`, does the last expression makes sense to you?

Comment: The variable `i` when used is an lvalue. If you had a pointer like `int *p = &i;` then `p` would be an lvalue too. But `&i` itself is *not* an lvalue. Perhaps you would be interested in [this value category reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category)? Note how [the list of non-lvalue expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category#Non-lvalue_object_expressions) includes "the address-of operator".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lvalue required as increment operand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364445/lvalue-required-as-increment-operand)

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: Re: “…does the last expression [`&i = &i + 1;`] make sense to you?” Sure, I think it moves `i` one location further up in memory. 

Comment: @Some programmer dude: Is there a way(maybe a short trick) to remember what is lvalue and what is not?!

Comment: The rule of thumb is, if you can apply the address-of operator `&` to something, then it's an lvalue.

Answer (score 2):

x++ results following steps.

```
1) read the value of x in to register.
2) increment the value of x
3) write the incremented value back to x (which means you are changing the value of x by '1')
```

But what you are trying to do is (&i)++ which means the following.

```
1) read address of i into register
2) increment the address by 1
3) write the incremented value in to address again? How you can change the address?
```

If you want to send the integer which is stored in next address to foo(), you need to increment as below.

```
int *p = &i + 1;
foo(p);
```

But that may result in undefined behavior because you know only address of i where i value is stored. Once you increment the address, you will get next address and it may contain some junk value.

Answer (score 1):

There is an attempt to apply the unary operator `&` to a temporary object that is evaluated as the expression `(&i)++`. You may not apply the operator to a temporary object.

C Standard (6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators):

> 1 **The operand of the unary & operator** shall be either a function designator, the result of a [] or unary * operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is not declared with the register storage-class specifier.

Comment: "*There is an attempt to apply the unary operator `&` to a temporary object ...*" sure? `&` is applied to `i`. To me it looks as if you mix up `&` and `++`.