# reading lines from text file into array

Tags: c, arrays, file

I have a text file that has the following lines:

```
(0,0) -180.000  77.500  -999.000  -999.000  -999.000  2740.831  45.000  -0.001  -0.001  0.000 458.138 45.000  -999.000
(1,0) -179.500  77.500  -999.000  -999.000  -999.000  2740.831  45.000  -0.001  -0.001  0.000 458.138 45.000  -999.000
(2,0) -179.000  77.500  -999.000  -999.000  -999.000  2740.831  45.000  -0.001  -0.001  0.000 458.138 45.000  -999.000
(3,0) -178.500  77.500  -999.000  -999.000  -999.000  2740.831  45.000  -0.001  -0.001  0.000 458.138 45.000  -999.000
...
...
(359,0) -0.500  77.500  -999.000  -999.000  -999.000  2740.831  45.000  -0.001  -0.001  0.000 458.138 45.000  -999.000
```

I am trying to put each line of this text file (buf) into an individual element of an array (buffarray) using the following program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 4*atan2(1,1)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    char buf[200];
    char *token;
    char buffarray[223920];
    char filename[150];
    int i, j, k;

    sscanf(argv[1], "%s", filename);

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "rt")) == NULL) {
        printf("Failed in fopen: %s\n", filename);
        return -1;
    }

    while (!feof(fp)) {
        fgets(buf, 200, fp);
        token = buf;
        printf("buf is %s\n", buf);     
        buffarray++ = token;
    }
}
```

How every when compiling this program I get an error message:

```
translate_ww3file.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
translate_ww3file.c:30:12: error: lvalue required as increment operand
   buffarray++ = token;
        ^
```

How do I resolve this issue?  I ideally want to create another text file where the lines are rearranged so that lines 180 to 359 from the original text are printed first in the new text file and then lines 1 to 179 are printing out afterwards in the new text file.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/3364548/1135469

Comment: One of many problems: [`while(!feof(fp))` always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941)

Comment: What should I be using?

Comment: Look closely at `buffarray++=token;`. Is this really what you want?

Comment: not sure what to use.

Comment: What are you trying to do in this line of code?

Comment: trying to read through the lines of the file.

Comment: I suggest that you step back from the code and try to describe each step in the process **in words**. Break down each step into as much details as you can.

Comment: Note that `buffarray++=token;` has nothing to do with reading lines of a file. I think you mean that is what the loop should do, but I was asking what this one line is supposed to do. For now I suggest that you remove that line entirely and see what happens.

Comment: What I am trying to do is read each line of the array and put them into an array.  I am able to successfully each each line but how to I put them into the array buffarray?

Comment: You already put each line into the array named `buf`. What do you want to do from there? Do you want the actual numerical values for each column? If so, you need to learn about `float` and `double`.

Comment: If all you want is to read all of the characters into one large array, then you should use `fread()` instead of `fgets()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple problems:

- the `PI` macro is not properly parenthesized. It should be `#define PI (4*atan2(1,1))`
- `while (!feof(fp))` is always wrong. Use `while (fgets(buf, 200, fp))` instead.
- You cannot increment an array, you want to concatenate the string at the end of the array with `strcat(buffarray, token);` but you must initialize `buffarray[0]` to `'\0'` before the loop.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PI  (4*atan2(1,1))

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    char buf[200];
    char *token;
    char buffarray[223920];
    char filename[150];

    if (argc < 2 || sscanf(argv[1], "%149s", filename) != 1) {
        printf("missing command line argument\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, "rt")) == NULL) {
        printf("Failed in fopen %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    *buffarray = '\0';
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        token = buf;
        printf("buf is %s\n", buf);     
        strcat(buffarray, token);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    printf("file contents:\n);
    fputs(buffarray, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: alternative to `#define PI (4*atan2(1,1))` --> `acos(-1)`.

Comment: @chux: yes indeed. I wonder why the Standard does not mandate a definition in `<math.h>` to the best approximation with the target floating point representation. `PI` is not used in the posted code anyway :)

Comment: When I make the array in the above program.  How can I have it set up so I can print out buffarray[i] for example.  If I want to print out one element of the array how do I do it?

Comment: @jms1980: if your goal is to parse a text file, converting the text to numbers, the method is inappropriate. You probably should use `sscanf()` to convert the line into a set of values that you would store in an array of structures. Can you clarify the problem?